# MySQL syntax:You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have written a very simple function:

```
function editCategory() {
    $ID         = urlencode($_GET['id']);
    $cname   = mysql_fix_string($_POST['cname']);
    $kabst   = mysql_fix_string($_POST['kabst']);
    $kselect    = $_POST['kselect'];
    $subsl      = $_POST['subsl'];
    $kradio     = $_POST['kradio'];
    $ksubmit    = $_POST['ksubmit'];

    if (isset($ksubmit)) {
        $query = "UPDATE category SET name = '$cname', description = '$kabst', published = '$kselect',  home = '$kradio', subcat = '$subsl'  WHERE id = $ID ";

        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if (mysql_affected_rows () == 1) {
            echo "ok";
        }
        else{
            echo mysql_error();
        }
    }
}

function mysql_fix_string($string)
{
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        $string = stripslashes(($string));
    return mysql_real_escape_string($string);
}
```

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

What is wrong?

Comment: Could you please echo out the resulting SQL query and give it to us?

Comment: @jasmine he means `echo $query`, before calling `mysql_query`, so we can see what the query looks like -- to find out where the error in it is.

Comment: if (!$query) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
Im sorry, this script made me mad :((
Only a white page...

Comment: not `if (!$query)` but `if(!$result)` and they said not `if` but `echo`. `echo $query;`

Comment: UPDATE category SET name = 'phpjhghjgjh', description = 'ssssssss', published = '1', home = '0', subcat = '1' WHERE id = 0

Comment: 0 here is because of intval. you have to get your id somewhere

Comment: You are right, without intval:
UPDATE category SET name = 'javascriptsss', description = 'sssss', published = '0', home = '1', subcat = '16' WHERE id = You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 and
id is lost!!!

Comment: id is lost because you don't have it in your form. add it either to the form's action or to the form's hidden field

Comment: It goes from category management field:
<a href=\"?event=editCat&id={$row['id']}\" class=\"editCat\" title=\"Edit\"></a>
and in URL:
dashboard/?event=editCat&id=2
Is this a wrong way?

Comment: @jasmine it doesn't as you have it on the form page but on the form handler page it's already lost. Every variable must be passed manually. See my another ansver for the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a very simple CRU<s>D</s> application, just to show how to pass an id:

```
<?
mysql_connect();
mysql_select_db("new");
$table="test";
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') { //form handler part:
  $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
  if ($id=intval($_POST['id'])) {
    $query="UPDATE $table SET name='$name' WHERE id=$id";
  } else {
    $query="INSERT INTO $table SET name='$name'";
  }
  mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$query);
  header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
  exit;
}
if (!isset($_GET['id'])) { //listing part:
  $LIST=array();
  $query="SELECT * FROM $table";
  $res=mysql_query($query);
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) $LIST[]=$row;
  include 'list.php';
} else { // form displaying part:

  if ($id=intval($_GET['id'])) {
    $query="SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id=$id";
    $res=mysql_query($query);
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    foreach ($row as $k => $v) $row[$k]=htmlspecialchars($v);
  } else {
    $row['name']='';
    $row['id']=0;
  }
  include 'form.php';
}
?>
```

File form.php:

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?=$row['name']?>"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$row['id']?>">
<input type="submit"><br>
<a href="?">Return to the list</a>
</form>
```

File list.php:

```
<a href="?id=0">Add item</a>
<? foreach ($LIST as $row): ?>
<li><a href="?id=<?=$row['id']?>"><?=$row['name']?></a>
<? endforeach ?>
```

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel
Your example solved my problem. I learned to get id from post not urlquery. Thanks for great help.

Comment: @jasmine though it can be passed via urlquery too. you have just to put it there. In my example it would be `<form method="POST" action="?id="<form method="POST">">` but I prefer to use urlquery to control my app's flow.

Answer (score 6):

```
$ID         = intval($_GET['id']); //using urlencode here is weird
$cname      =  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cname']); 
//and the same for the rest ALL.
$kradio     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['kradio']);
```

Also,

```
$ksubmit    = $_POST['ksubmit']; 
if (isset($ksubmit)) {
```

is senseless.
$ksubmit would be always set
it should be

```
if (isset($_POST['ksubmit'])) {
```

To be sure you have all variables, please add these lines at the top of the script:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Better yet `if(true != empty($_POST['ksubmit']))`

Comment: function mysql_fix_string($string)
  {
  if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
  $string = stripslashes(($string));
  return mysql_real_escape_string($string);
 }

The same problem...

Comment: @jasmine But you are. 1. this function is wrong. it must be mysql_real_escape_string and nothing else. 2. it must be applied to all fields which you have enclosed in quotes in the query, not only two. 3. Do you have $_GET['id'] variable? See addon to my post.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: id in /home/***/public_html/cms/dashboard/includes/database.php  on line 255

Comment: @jasmine quod erat demonstrandum, which means "that which was to be demonstrated". Pascal were right, you don't pass id wia GET method to your post. It's either in the POST or weren't sent at all

Comment: @Col Empty values are generally useless. I prefer to not waste my time with a second statement asking if the value is empty or not. 9 times out of 10, if it is an empty value, it is just as useful as not being set at all. And most certainly, I do understand the meaning of the operator.

Comment: @Chacha102 no, you don't :) 1. using `true` constant here is senseless. `if(empty($_POST['ksubmit']))` is enough. 2. we're checking merely if button were pressed, not it's value. So, isset is enough in every way.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that :

- For fields that are strings (varchar/char) in the DB :

  - the values you're passing are properly enclosed with quotes
  - the content of the values you're passing must be escaped : if there is a quote in what the user POSTed, it must be escaped -- see [**`mysql_real_escape_string`**](http://fr.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)
- For fields that are integers in the DB :

  - You must pass integer values
  - which can be ensured by calling [**`intval`**](http://fr.php.net/intval) on the values POSTed by the user

Here, you should probably :

- Use `intval()` on `$_GET['id']`
- Use `mysql_real_escape_string` on some other fields.

  - JUdging from the query, in which all fields, except `id` are enclosed with single-quotes, I'd say you have to use `mysql_real_escape_string` on all fields -- except `id`, of course.

As a sidenote :

- You are using `$_GET` for `id`
- And `$_POST` for everything else.

Is that on purpose ?

Comment: function mysql_fix_string($string)
  {
  if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
  $string = stripslashes(($string));
  return mysql_real_escape_string($string);
 }

But the same problem with intval() and mysql_real_escape_string

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an empty variable.

And do something against SQL injection, everybody can hack your database. With a little luck, you're the one killing your database... Use mysql_real_escape_string() for all user input into your queries.

Comment: function mysql_fix_string($string)
  {
  if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
  $string = stripslashes(($string));
  return mysql_real_escape_string($string);
 }

this is the same with mysql_real_escape_string() ;)

and "Im not" the one killing "my" database

Comment: And why do you protect just a few parameters against SQL injection and leave the others vulnerable? You're still killing your database, sorry for the bad news.

Comment: I didnot know that it is necessary for select and radio buttons. Thanks for bad news.

Comment: @jasmine it is necessary for the every field you put in the query, no matter from where it came. it 's not user input matter but SQL matter. Every value you enclose in quotes in the query, must be passed through mysql_real_escape_string. No exceptions. No conditions. No matter it came from the radiobutton or a text file.